# Flask Webapp - Verify Email after Registration - Best Practice

Tags: python, flask, itsdangerous

I've been following along to [Corey Schafer's awesome youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwZwr5Tvyxo&list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH) on the basic flaskblog. In addition to Corey's code, I`d like to add a logic, where users have to verify their email-address before being able to login. I've figured to do this with the URLSafeTimedSerializer from itsdangerous, like suggested by [prettyprinted here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vF9n248M1yk).
The whole token creation and verification process seems to work. Unfortunately due to my very fresh python knowledge in general, I can't figure out a clean way on my own how to get that saved into the sqlite3 db. In my models I've created a Boolean Column email_confirmed with default=False which I am intending to change to True after the verification process. My question is: how do I best identify the user (for whom to alter the email_confirmed Column) when he clicks on his custom url? Would it be a good practice to also save the token inside a db Column and then filter by that token to identify the user?
Here is some of the relevant code:

**User Class in my modely.py**

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default_profile.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    date_registered = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    email_confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False, default=False)
    email_confirm_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    projects = db.relationship('Project', backref='author', lazy=True)


    def get_mail_confirm_token(self, expires_sec=1800):
        s = URLSafeTimedSerializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_sec)
        return s.dumps(self.email, salt='email-confirm')


    @staticmethod
    def verify_mail_confirm_token(token):
        s = URLSafeTimedSerializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try: 
            return s.loads(token, salt='email-confirm', max_age=60)
        except SignatureExpired:
            return "PROBLEM"
```

**Registration Logic in my routes (using a users blueprint):**

```
@users.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated: 
        return redirect(url_for('dash.dashboard'))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        send_mail_confirmation(user)
        return redirect(url_for('users.welcome'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)


@users.route('/welcome')
def welcome():
    return render_template('welcome.html')


@users.route('/confirm_email/<token>')
def confirm_email(token):
    user = User.verify_mail_confirm_token(token)
    current_user.email_confirmed = True
    current_user.email_confirm_date = datetime.utcnow 
    return user
```

The last parts `current_user.email_confirmed = True` and `current_user.email_confirm_date =datetime.utcnow` are probably the lines in question. Like stated above the desired entries aren't made because the user is not logged in at this stage, yet.
Im grateful for any help on this!
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to your question is this:

> My question is: how do I best identify the user (for whom to alter the email_confirmed Column) when he clicks on his custom url?

The answer can be seen [in the example on URL safe serialisation using itsdangerous](https://itsdangerous.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/url_safe/).

The token itself *contains* the e-mail address, because that's what you are using inside your `get_mail_confirm_token()` function.

You can then use the serialiser to retrieve the e-mail address from that token. You can do that inside your `verify_mail_confirm_token()` function, but, because it's a static-method you still need a session. You can pass this in as a separate argument though without problem. You also should treat the `BadSignature` exception from `itsdangerous`. It would then become:

```
@staticmethod
def verify_mail_confirm_token(session, token):
    s = URLSafeTimedSerializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    try: 
        email = s.loads(token, salt='email-confirm', max_age=60)
    except (BadSignature, SignatureExpired):
        return "PROBLEM"

    user = session.query(User).filter(User.email == email).one_or_none()
    return user
```

> Would it be a good practice to also save the token inside a db Column and then filter by that token to identify the user?

No. The token should be short-lived and should not be kept around.

Finally, in your `get_mail_confirm_token` implementation you are not using the `URLSafeTimedSerializer` class correctly. You pass in a second argument called `expires_sec`, but if you [look at the docs](https://itsdangerous.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/url_safe/#itsdangerous.url_safe.URLSafeTimedSerializer) you will see that the second argument is the salt, which might lead to unintended problems.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot in solving my issue! I'll post my final running code snippets below.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @exhuma. Here is how I eventually got it to work - also in addition I'm posting the previously missing part of email-sending.

**User Class in my models.py**

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default="default_profile.jpg")
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    date_registered = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    email_confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False, default=False)
    email_confirm_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    projects = db.relationship("Project", backref="author", lazy=True)

    def get_mail_confirm_token(self):
        s = URLSafeTimedSerializer(
            current_app.config["SECRET_KEY"], salt="email-comfirm"
        )
        return s.dumps(self.email, salt="email-confirm")

    @staticmethod
    def verify_mail_confirm_token(token):
        try:
            s = URLSafeTimedSerializer(
                current_app.config["SECRET_KEY"], salt="email-confirm"
            )
            email = s.loads(token, salt="email-confirm", max_age=3600)
            return email
        except (SignatureExpired, BadSignature):
            return None
```

**Send Mail function in my utils.py**

```
def send_mail_confirmation(user):
    token = user.get_mail_confirm_token()
    msg = Message(
        "Please Confirm Your Email",
        sender="noreply@demo.com",
        recipients=[user.email],
    )
    msg.html = render_template("mail_welcome_confirm.html", token=token)
    mail.send(msg)
```

**Registration Logic in my routes.py (using a users blueprint):**

```
@users.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for("dash.dashboard"))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode(
            "utf-8"
        )
        user = User(
            username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password
        )
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        send_mail_confirmation(user)
        return redirect(url_for("users.welcome"))
    return render_template("register.html", form=form)


@users.route("/welcome")
def welcome():
    return render_template("welcome.html")


@users.route("/confirm_email/<token>")
def confirm_email(token):
    email = User.verify_mail_confirm_token(token)
    if email:
        user = db.session.query(User).filter(User.email == email).one_or_none()
        user.email_confirmed = True
        user.email_confirm_date = datetime.utcnow()
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for("users.login"))
        flash(
            f"Your email has been verified and you can now login to your account",
            "success",
        )
    else:
        return render_template("errors/token_invalid.html")
```

**Only missing** from my point of view is a simple conditional logic, to check if email_confirmed = True before logging in, as well as the same check inside the confirm_email(token) function to not make this process repeatable in case the user clicks on the confirmation link several times. Thanks again! Hope this is of some help to anyone else!